# Script required on page in Wordpress, what's the best practice?

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I have some JQ plugins I need to initialise **ON** page (*front-page.php*) in my Wordpress installation.

I.e. *I need the following script embedded just below the `</body>` tag.*

What's the best practice here?

> All of my scripts are registered and enqueued as recommended per the [Wordpress codex](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/).

```
</body>
  <script>
    // . Plugin Init

    $(window).on('load', function () {
      // initialization of svg injector module
      $.HSCore.components.HSSVGIngector.init('.js-svg-injector');
    });

    $(document).on('ready', function () {
      // initialization of slick carousel
      $.HSCore.components.HSSlickCarousel.init('.js-slick-carousel');
    });

    // . End Plugin Init
  </script>
```

I've looked at [wp_localize_script](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) but I'm pretty sure it's not what I need (*Could be wrong*). 
Any help I could get pointing me in the right direction would be greatly appreciated.

Here's what I'm currently using in my footer.php file;

```
<?php if ( is_front_page() ) : ?>
    <!-- JS Plugins Init. -->
    <script>
        jQuery(window).on('load', function () {
         // initialization of svg injector module
        jQuery.HSCore.components.HSSVGIngector.init('.js-svg-injector');
         });

        jQuery(document).on('ready', function () {
        // initialization of slick carousel
        jQuery.HSCore.components.HSSlickCarousel.init('.js-slick-carousel');
        });
    </script>
<?php endif; ?>
```

> To clarify I don't need a file.js embedded. I need the raw code embedded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Original answer

*How do you place JavaScript links before `</body>` instead of inside `<head>`?*

As per [the documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) this is done when you enqueue the script. Simply do something like

```
wp_enqueue_script('script_handle', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__).'script.js', [], null, TRUE);
```

where the last parameter, `TRUE`, tells `wp_enqueue_script()` to insert before `</body>` instead of `</head>`

### Updated answer

*How do you output the raw JavaScript after `</body>`?*

The function we need, `wp_print_scripts()`, was deprecated in Wordpress 3.3 and replaced by, you guessed it, `wp_enqueue_script()`. If you want to append a script you've registered, you can use [`wp_add_inline_script('script_handle', $data)`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_add_inline_script/) which will output whatever you put inside the second argument, `$data`, inside `<script></script>`-tags immediately after where the link to the enqueued script was placed.

As for placing it outside the `<body>` I'm guessing you would have to create your own plugin because the designer of the theme, and the developers of Wordpress, will invariably have placed all output inside `<head>` and `<body>`-tags, as this is the correct way to do it according to the HTML specification.

Comment: You are correct however, this doesn't output the raw script into the page though? I need the raw script output. With the <script></script> tags. Apologies, I might not have been clear in my question. Please see the updated code in my question.

Comment: Force of habit, I usually embed scripts on the outside.

Comment: @Beaniie I've updated my answer to reflect your updated question

Comment: Thanks for the update, its interesting, I did stumble upon inline_script. However I ran into a problem with multiple "" '' ``. I've amended my question to show my current work around. Would you say what I have done is bad practice?

Comment: Well, yes, it's bad practice in the sense that it breaks the coding conventions set up by Wordpress. That can of course make it harder for others, and yourself a few months later, to understand the structure of your code and where things are placed. However, it becomes a case of cost versus gain. Almost every code project has these types of hacky solutions to some degree because doing things by the book would mean an investment in time which is often too expensive.

Comment: Understood, I think I'll get away with it in this scenario! Thanks again.